# Back button help

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Hi guys i have a problem with the browsers back button when i click on it.

The problem is I log into my webapp and the home page appears. when i click the back button of the browser. i can see the login page. But i don't want this to happen i want the session to be maintained throught till i click the log out button.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a dynamic webapp you need to set the appropriate http headers which will "kill" any browser or proxy cache. The usual recipe is:

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache"); //HTTP 1.1
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); //prevents caching at the proxy server
```

That way, going back to the login screen should fetch the page from server. And if your server side logic is correct, you will redirect the user to his home page or dashboard since he is already logged in.